# Не переходит на php файл по ссылке

Tags: php, html

```
<?php
require_once 'ShowDesc.php';

echo '<a href="ShowDesc.php">ССЫЛКА</a>';
```

Почему не переходит? Точнее, вроде как переходит, но информация старого скрипта остаётся.

Comment: Зачем Вам переходить на "ShowDesc.php" если Вы уже его подключили в файл?

Comment: Сейчас отключил. Все равно не переходит

Comment: Не понятна суть проблемы. Уточните вопрос. Приведите скриншоты. Листинги кода.

Comment: Я пытаюсь перейти на новую страницу, но оно буд-то не видет файл Showdesc.php. Всегда выводится информация из index.php. Даже если я введу localhost:8080/asdasufhasufasukfaskuf, все-равно инфа с index.php

Comment: Конфигурацию веб-сервера покажите.
Есть ли файл .htaccess ?

Comment: Во-первых, если я не ошибаюсь, то не нужно использовать `require_once ` в данной ситуации, а во-вторых попробуй в атрибут `href` написать `/ShowDesc.php`или `http://site.com/ShowDesc.php`